# Binary Search Tree in-order traversal using Iterator & Stack - SPACE complexity O(log N)? How?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

During the phone interview, I was asked to implement Binary Search Tree in-order traversal using an Iterator & Stack (*not recursively*). I was not allowed to use a parent pointer.

This is the starter code that I was given.

```
struct TreeNode {
int val;
TreeNode *left;
TreeNode *right;
TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}};

class BTIterator
{
public:
    BTIterator(TreeNode *root){


    };
    TreeNode* next() {

    }
    bool hasNext() {

    }

};
```

Test function:

```
void TestFunc(TreeNode *root) {
BTIterator bti(root);
while(bti->hasNext()) {
  cout << bti->next()->val << " ";
}}
```

I was specifically asked to implement `BTIterator`, `next`, `hasNext` in the above code.

So I did.
Follow up questions were what are the time & space complexity.
So I answered time is O(N), space is O(N).
However, the interviewer said "You can reduce the space complexity further to 
 O(log N)". I asked him how and he said "we only need to store the parents". (I could have heard him wrong. He had a very thick accent.) My implementation was storing every nodes that has left children. I just took his answer for granted.

However, after the interview, I think, even if we only need to store the parents (not the leaf node) it's still O(N). It's precisley O(N/2) but that's still O(N). I believe **any node who has left children** should be stored in the stack. How not to?

The only time when the space O(logN) could be achieved is when the binary tree has only one branch that keeps doing down (not a balanced tree with full leaves.)

What am I missing here? If anyone could explain how the space complexity using the iterator can be reduced further to O(log N), I will appreciate a lot!

Comment: You'd have to actually work at it to make it other than O(logN) space -- the obvious way of having a stack object in your BTIterator is O(logN) as logN is the max stack depth required at any instant.  What did you manage to do that wasn't O(logN)?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Space would be O(n) to save `n` nodes?!!

Comment: @vish4071: you only need to store the maximum tree depth on the stack -- O(logn) average case, though as the answer below notes, O(n) worst case if you have an unbalanced binary tree that is basically a list.

Comment: ohh...learnt something new @ChrisDodd. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion.

Consider this tree (just so we have a concrete example to refer to):

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C
     / \   / \
    D   E F   G
```

Over the course of iterating over this tree, you will need to store every single node that has a left-child — the three nodes `A`, `B`, and `C`. In general, for any tree, you'll need to store up to *O*(*n*) nodes over the course of your iteration. This seems to be why you say *O*(*n*).

But you don't need to keep all of those nodes *at once*. Once you've iterated forward to `E`, you no longer need to keep node `B` for anything. At any given point in the iteration, you only need to keep *later* ancestors of the *current* node — which is at most ever two nodes, namely `A` and `B` (when your current node is `D`). In general, for any tree, you'll never need to store more than *O*(*h*) nodes at the same time, where *h* is the height of the tree. Assuming a balanced tree (as your interviewer clearly is), that means *O*(log *n*).

So you don't need *O*(*n*) extra space, because you can reuse space over time. That's kind of the point of using a stack: you can pop an element from the top, then push a new element in its place.

Comment: Ah... at once! was the keyword. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the Binary Search Tree(BST) is unbalanced and we have to use stack method, then `O(h)` is the space complexity, where `h` is the height of the given BST. Apparently, it is **not possible** to achieve better space complexity if stack method is to be followed.

If the given BST is balanced or if you are allowed to balance it, then it is possible to achieve `O(logn)` space complexity where `n` is the number of nodes in the given BST.

Obviously, if you are not forced to use the stack method, you can play around with trade-offs of time and space complexity. If preprocessing is allowed, use [Morris in-order traversal using threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Morris_in-order_traversal_using_threading) for `O(n)` extra space and `O(1)` time complexity. Alternatively, if preprocessing is not allowed, you can just store the `current` TreeNode. When `next()` is called, find the least upper bound of the stored current TreeNode in `O(logn)` time for balanced BST and in `O(n)` time for unbalanced BST. Update `current` before return from `next()`. Thus you could trade time for `O(1)` space complexity.